# SQL takes too long to run

Tags: sql

Both a and c are the same table with 400 records. b and d are the same table too with 300 records. Yet takes about 4 mins to run this. How can I speed this up?

```
select a.docref
from a
left outer b
on a.cono=b.cono and a.tt=b.tt and a.docref=b.docref
where a.cono='VC'
and b.accn08='9005100'
and a.pstper=11609
and a.cbpref not in  (select c.cbpref
                      from  c
                      left outer join d
                      on c.cono=d.cono and c.tt=d.tt and c.docref=d.docref
                      where c.cono='VC'
                      and d.accn08='9005100'
                      and c.pstper=11609
                      and c.tt='RX')
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `NOT IN` takes a bit more time. Try `LEFT JOIN` and add a condition where `ID IS NULL` :

```
SEELCT a.docref
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b
ON a.cono=b.cono 
AND a.tt=b.tt 
AND a.docref=b.docref
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT c.cbpref
  FROM c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN d
  ON c.cono=d.cono AND c.tt=d.tt AND c.docref=d.docref
  WHERE c.cono='VC'
  AND d.accn08='9005100'
  AND c.pstper=11609
  AND c.tt='RX'
)tb
ON tb.cbpref = a.cbpref
AND a.cbpref IS NULL
WHERE a.cono='VC'
AND b.accn08='9005100'
AND a.pstper=11609
```